# Firebase retrieve data from multiple nodes based on common ID

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a social application. I am using Firebase as my backend(API's). I am not able to run a single query to get all the desired data. My database structure is as follows:

```
**post**
{
 "postID1":
 { url: "http://stackoverflow.com" 
   desc: "some description here" } 
 "postID2": 
  { url: "http://google.com"
   desc: "again some description here"
 } 
}
**album**
{
  postID1:
{
     albumID1:
     {
          type: 'Image'
          name: 'my first album'
     }

}
    postID2:
{
     albumID2:
     {
          type: 'youtube'
          name: 'my second album'
          url: 'http://youtube.com'
     }

}
**media**
albumID1
{
 mediaID1:
 {
  type: 'abc'
  desc: 'some description'
 }
}
```

I want to get all the posts including all the media files in it.
e.g I want to first get the "postID1" then it's album and then media files, all the 3 nodes connected to each other via postID which is unique. Same for "postID2" and so on... In the example I have explained about albums and media related to post but in the same way I want to retrieve data from other nodes like Hashtags, Comments,Likes etc.

Answer (score 1):

With this structure you will not able to fetch data using single query.
You have 2 options.

1)Either you change your structure like this.

```
**post**
-> "postID1":
 -> url: "http://stackoverflow.com" 
 -> desc: "some description here" 
 -> albumID1
          ->  type: 'Image'
          ->  name: 'my first album'
          ->  mediaID1:
                   ->  type: 'abc'
                   -> desc: 'some description'
```

Because as we know that firebase is noSQL so no need to follow sql rules.
By this structure you can get all data in one query

2) You can write multiple query in your current structure.
  Like first you fetch data from post table then with post id you can get data from album and then from album id you can fetch data from media table.

Comment: As I have already setup the database and most of the functionality is already working. I want to go for option 2.

But still I am facing some issues writing multiple queries as firebase runs queries asynchronously. At the time I am fetching all posts , In the same loop I want to get the first postID and the related data (Albums,Media) then the loop should do the same for postID2 and so on.
But now what is happening is at the time I am getting all the posts the album query is also running simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I focus on the **album** side. You can also do the same for **media**.

For the **post** node one query is enough

You can try this :

```
for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    for (DataSnapshot  dataSnapshot1:postSnapshot.getChildren()){
        //do something here            
    }        
}
```